# How to delete duplicate data in hive table with partition?

Tags: hadoop, hive, duplicates

The duplicate data from 2023-03-26 to 2023-07-10 must be removed.
I'm trying to remove duplicates from the table using this command, but I'm getting an error.

Commands:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict; INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.table_name PARTITION(dt) select distinct * from db.table_name where dt >= '2023-03-26' AND dt >= '2023-07-10';
```

Error:

```
23/07/26 16:07:46 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0]: WARN io.CombineHiveRecordReader: Multiple     partitions found; not going to pass a part spec to LLAP IO: {{dt=2023-07-10}} and {{dt=2023-07-11}} 2023-   07-26 16:07:47,952 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0% 23/07/26 16:07:47 [aabca681-0714-44f6-bc8d-9be6d7fca9fc    main]: WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use     org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead.
```

Note: The partition of this table is just the dates.
Example:

```
show partitions db.table_name;
dt=2023-07-04
dt=2023-07-05
dt=2023-07-06
dt=2023-07-07
dt=2023-07-08
dt=2023-07-09
dt=2023-07-10
```

```
$ hive --version
Hive 2.3.3
```

Hope you can suggest on this one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db.table_name PARTITION(dt)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM db.table_name
WHERE dt BETWEEN '2023-03-26' AND '2023-07-10';
```

Comment: Let me try this :) thanks!

Comment: I still got the same message :( 


23/07/27 04:16:45 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0]: WARN io.CombineHiveRecordReader: Multiple partitions found; not going to pass a part spec to LLAP IO: {{dt=2023-03-26}} and {{dt=2023-03-27}}

Comment: What is your table ddl can you post it